# Symfony2 checkboxes & Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to record a choice of checkboxes in my data base. I get this error:

> ContextErrorException: Notice: Array to string conversion in //vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 120

**My form :**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('adult_available', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array('A' => 'Adult', 'C' => 'Children'),
            'required'  => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ));
```

**My field :**

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="CHAR(1) NOT NULL")
     */
    protected $adult_available;
```

My form looks good! But when I submit I got the ContextErrorException exception

Thanks!

Comment: That field holds a single value, but you have allowed the form to expect multiple values.

Comment: You say that is my field is wrong : @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="CHAR(1) NOT NULL") ?

Comment: I don't know whether the field should be a collection, or if the form should only return a single value on submit.  I only know that at the moment it looks like they contradict each other.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very new with symfony and doctrine. I would like to store in database a multiple choice (with chexboxes) but without create a new entity. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="adult_available", type="simple_array")
 */
private $adultAvailable;
```

Comment: @user2775846 tick me then! :)